# How do I parse a sentence with two verbs?

Tags: verbs

I know that we usually break sentences down into subject, verb, object. But the following sentence is causing me problems:

> I want to give a present.

How do I parse this?

- Is *want* the verb and *give a present* the object?
- Is *want to give* the verb, and *a present* the object?

Comment: It has two verbs. "to give" is an infinitive.

Comment: "Want" is a verb, and "to give a present" is its complement, not object. "A present" is object of "give".

Comment: Please go to a dictionary and see how those verbs work before posting. Especially give.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 verbs in the sentence. One modal and one infinitive.

"To want" is a modal verb. Modal verbs requires another verb in the sentence to be in infinitive.

"I"is the subject of the sentence. 
"Want" is a modal verb.
"To give" is the infinitive verb.
"a present" is an object.

> I want to give you a present.
>   I wish to take your present.
>   I ought to buy some presents

Some modals removes the "to" part from the infinitive:

> I could give you a present.
>   I must take your present. 
>   I may sell you present.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I parse a sentence with two verbs?

There are things called *infinitives*, *gerunds*, and *participles* - these use the same words as verbs, but have the function of nouns or modifiers.  The category for these are *verbals*.

There's many words in English that can work outside of the function they are "supposed" to be (and many that can't).  A lot of nouns can be "hacked" into working as verbs, and verbals are a "sanctioned" way for verbs to work other parts of speech.

> I know that we usually break sentences down into subject, verb, object.

Objects are nouns - so verbals that work as nouns can appear where an object is expected.

> I want to give a present.

*To give* is the object of *want* (What does "I" want?  To give.)

Verbals are not functioning as verbs, but they can still take objects themselves like verbs.  What they can't take are subjects.

So *a present* is an object of *to give*.